# Remove maximum value of two vectors in R

Tags: r

I have 4 vectors `v1, a1, v2, a2`. I want to write a code which can uses for both `v1 and a1` or `v2 and a2` to remove the maximum value of vector `v1` and also remove the elements of `a1` according to length of max value of `v1` , also this code works for `v2` which removes the maximun value and remove according value in `a2`. How can I do this in R? I would like the code could works for any other vectors like these are.

```
    v1 = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 5, 6, 6.5, 8, 8, 8)

    a1 = rep(1, length(v1))

    v2=unique(v1)

    a2 = c(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3)
```

my desire result is as follows:

```
     > v1
     [1] 0.25 0.25 0.30 0.30 0.30 5.00 6.00 6.50
     > a1
     [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
     > a2
     [1] 2 3 1 1 1
      > v2
     [1] 0.25 0.30 5.00 6.00 6.50
```

Comment: Can you show what results are you expecting?

Comment: What do you mean by "length of the max value of `v1`"?

Comment: Means that length(mav(v1)) = 3.

Comment: `max` returns a single number, so its vector `length` should be 1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for each vector individually:

```
v1[-which(v1==max(v1))]
a1[-which(v1==max(v1))]
```

But it probably makes more sense to bind them together so you don't have to repeat commands, like:

```
cbind(v1,a1)[-which(v1==max(v1)),]
```

The process would be the same for `v2` and `a2`:

```
cbind(v2,a2)[-which(v2==max(v2)),]
```

I should also add that it's possible to do this without `which` with slightly different syntax:

```
cbind(v1,a1)[!v1==max(v1),]
cbind(v2,a2)[!v2==max(v2),]
```